# Springfox Boot Starter 3.0.0 JsonSerializer Error

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springfox, swagger-3.0

I am using **io.springfox** 3.0.0 version in my project.  I added the dependency to my build.gradle file as following:

`implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-boot-starter', version: '3.0.0'`

The external libraries were created as expected:

```
io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0
io.springfox:springfox-core:3.0.0
io.springfox:springfox-data-rest:3.0.0
io.springfox:springfox-oas:3.0.0
io.springfox:springfox-schema:3.0.0
io.springfox:springfox-spi:3.0.0
io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:3.0.0
io.springfox:springfox-spring-web-flux:3.0.0
io.springfox:springfox-spring-web-mvc:3.0.0
io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotation:2.1.2
io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models:2.1.2
```

I am using Spring Boot 2.4.2 and Java 11.

When I run my Spring boot application, I get the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'swagger2ControllerWebMvc' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/rally/dynamicscreen-service/lib/springfox-swagger2.jar!/springfox/documentation/swagger2/web/Swagger2ControllerWebMvc.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonSerializer' defined in springfox.documentation.spring.web.SpringfoxWebConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.JsonSerializer]: Factory method 'jsonSerializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/swagger/v3/oas/models/OpenAPI

Where could I be doing wrong?